# linking to files that matches filenames

Tags: unix

I have a filenames filenames.txt that contains the filenames of the files I want to copy between two directories. Any idea how to do this. I assume `find` could be used?

filenames.txt

```
file1
file2
file3
```

Directory to copy from:

```
file1
file2
file3
file4
file5
...
```

out:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Dry-run no-change initial `awk` script:

```
awk '{printf("cp \"%s\" \"%s\"\n",$0,"target_folder")}' filenames.txt
```

Change `target_folder` to your desired folder.

#### 2. Inspect the `cp` commands result.

#### 3. Execute the `cp` commands in 1 line:

```
bash <<< $(awk '{printf("cp \"%s\" \"%s\"\n",$0,"target_folder")}' filenames.txt)
```